# Having trouble in adding css and js file into view in codeigniter framework

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

i have a problem in flowing segment of code, problem is that content of view are not display in browser.

This is my view part:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>files/css/cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>files/js/myjs.js" >
    </head>
    <body>
    <div  class="block_box">
    <h1>This is from welcome messege view</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" onclick"=myfun()" value="Click Me" /> 
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This is my css fle:i

```
 .block_box{
            background-color:blue;
            border-color:white;
            border-width:1px;
            height:200px;
            width:400px;
        }
```

this is my java script file:

```
        function myfun(){
        alert("I am from java script file");
        }
```

and my directory structure for js and css file is:

// c/wamp/myproect/files/cssfile.css sand same as for js file,

Comment: What is your base_url() ?

Comment: Change `onclick"=myfun()"` of button to  `onclick="myfun()" `

Comment: rhttp://localhost/myproject/ this is my base url

Comment: Go to your page source and check what the final link is being rendered in HTML. Tell us what that link is, along with your `base_url()` is

Comment: and after changing onclick"=myfun()" to onclick="myfun()" no effect is done

Comment: Are you placing css and js in folders named css and js ?

Comment: if your directory structure is c/wamp/myproect/files/cssfile.css how come you have the css path as <?php echo base_url(); ?>files/**css**/cssfile.css

Comment: yes i have two folders in files folder name as js and css

Comment: can you do a view source and tell what is the href that you see?

Comment: Did you try hard-coding the links to css and js files? Do they work? If they do, maybe you haven't set your `base_url()` properly. You can check that in your `application/config/config.php` file.

Comment: `problem is that content of view are not display in browser`. Thats the main problem. Noone knows what being displayed and guessing.

Comment: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\files\css\cssfile.css for css and 
C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\files\js\myjs.js for js

Comment: and is this the path for your css and js file?

Comment: You have invalid HTML that is causing the page to not render. See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `</script>` tag. Should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>files/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey @TunaMaxx can you help me i want to validate a form using jquery and i am new to jquery so what is the steps to validate a form using jquery????

Comment: Ask a new question and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: i am unable to post new question, can you help me in comments??

Comment: Sorry, no. That doesn't help anyone out, and it would have nothing to do with this current question. Why can't you post a new question?

Comment: actually i am new to stackoverflow and i dont know the standards or quality of questions so due to low quality of question i am unable to post my next question...

Comment: Understood. You can use Stack Overflow to search for existing questions similar to your too. You don't have to ask a new question every time.

Comment: but i have a problem, and when i am searching on stack overflow then none of question is show mine type......